# Got error when Failed to resolve component: router-link in laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, bootstrap-5

I'm new to Vue and laravel. So I create a laravel project with vue inertia and trying to use bootstrap libray. I use one of the header into my header layout but got error `Failed to resolve component: router-link` and it become unclickable. What possibly had happen because I didn't change any of the code from bootstrap. My setups are generated from laravel cli. I did try install the router using npm but still not working

app.js

```
createInertiaApp({
    title: (title) => `${title} - ${appName}`,
    resolve: (name) => resolvePageComponent(`./Pages/${name}.vue`, import.meta.glob('./Pages/**/*.vue')),
    setup({ el, App, props, plugin }) {
        return createApp({ render: () => h(App, props) })
            .use(plugin)
            .use(ZiggyVue)
            .mount(el);
    },
    progress: {
        color: '#4B5563',
    },
});
```

Header.vue from bootstrap

```
<template>
    <header>
        <!-- Navbar -->
        <MDBNavbar expand="lg" light bg="white" container>
            <MDBNavbarToggler
                target="#navbarExample02"
                @click="collapse2 = !collapse2"
            ></MDBNavbarToggler>
            <MDBCollapse id="navbarExample02" v-model="collapse2">
                <MDBNavbarNav class="mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                    <MDBNavbarItem to="#" active>
                        Home
                    </MDBNavbarItem>
                    <MDBNavbarItem to="#">
                        Features
                    </MDBNavbarItem>
                    <MDBNavbarItem to="#">
                        Pricing
                    </MDBNavbarItem>
                    <MDBNavbarItem to="#">
                        About
                    </MDBNavbarItem>
                </MDBNavbarNav>
            </MDBCollapse>
        </MDBNavbar>
        <!-- Navbar -->
        <!-- Background image -->
        <div
            class="p-5 text-center bg-image"
            style="
        background-image: url('https://mdbootstrap.com/img/new/slides/041.webp');
        height: 400px;
      "
        >
            <div class="mask" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center h-100">
                    <div class="text-white">
                        <h1 class="mb-3">Heading</h1>
                        <h4 class="mb-3">Subheading</h4>
                        <MDBBtn tag="a" lg outline="light"
                                href="#!"
                                role="button"
                        >Call to action
                        </MDBBtn>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Background image -->
    </header>
</template>
<script>
import { MDBBtn, MDBNavbar, MDBNavbarToggler, MDBNavbarNav, MDBNavbarItem, MDBCollapse } from 'mdb-vue-ui-kit';
import { ref } from 'vue';
// import router from "./router";

export default {
    components: {
        MDBBtn,
        MDBNavbar,
        MDBNavbarToggler,
        MDBNavbarNav,
        MDBNavbarItem,
        MDBCollapse,
    },
    setup() {
        const collapse2 = ref(false);
        return { collapse2 };
    },
};
</script>
```

And the error is [image]

Comment: Maybe it need the vue-router ?

Comment: i think you should replace the MDBNavbarItem with inertia router link see https://inertiajs.com/links because routing in inertia is diffrent than the normal spa routing